# Selecting individual items from multiple columns in ListBox

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I am trying to create a listbox with the column headers of my data to use that as an input from the user on which columns the user wants displayed in the final result. So far I've been able to divide the listbox into two columns and populate the relevant data in it, but on selecting the items, it is selecting the complete row and not individual items.

Can you please let me know how can I select individual items from a multicolumn listbox.

Here's the code :

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Enter()
Dim firstrow As Range
Dim c_no As Integer
Dim Arr() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Set firstrow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tag Dump").Range("A1:AR1")
With firstrow
c = .Cells.Count
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ReDim Preserve Arr(c, 2)

'If WorksheetFunction.IsEven(c) = True Then
For i = 1 To c / 2
    Arr(i, 1) = Sheets("Tag Dump").Cells(1, i).Value
    Arr(i, 2) = Sheets("Tag Dump").Cells(1, i + (c / 2)).Value

'ElseIf WorksheetFunction.IsEven(c) = False Then
'End If

With ListBox1
    .ColumnCount = 2
    .Additem
    .List(i - 1, 0) = Arr(i, 1)
    .List(i - 1, 1) = Arr(i, 2)

End With
Next
With ListBox1
    .ListStyle = fmListStyleOption
    .Font = "Arial"
    .MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectExtended
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Here's an image of the result I'm getting:
[Listbox selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6ILA.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't. Either you use multple listbox and synchronize them, or you go on as you are and ignore the selected columns you don't need

Comment: Okay, I'll try to do this with multiple listboxes. Thanks.